# SSIS - EXECUTE PROCESS TASK The process exit code was "16" while the expected was "0"

Tags: ssis

IN The SSIS package I am getting execute process task error; exit code was 16 expected was 0 I am using robocopy however when I use robcopy from command prompt it successfully copy my zip files from one folder to another folder.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A return code of 16 suggest you have permissions issues. If you are running your package via SSDT/BIDS, make sure you are running it as an administrator.

To open BIDS/SSDT as an administrator, right click on the shortcut and hit run as administrator, then open your solution.

If you are running it via Sql server agent job make sure the user/proxy account you are using has required access/permission.

Comment: I have opened BIDS as an administrator . Still the issue is same.  Your Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Create a .bat file and paste your command in the .bat file. Now you can schedule this .bat file using Execute process task in SSIS run this .bat file and schedule your SSIS package.

Comment: I tried this too. Now. I am getting The process exit code was "-1073741510" while the expected was "0". :(

Comment: I have used this Robocopy C:\\Source\\datafile c:\\Destination *.* /mon:1 /r:2000  in bat file and it had copied the files however Execution Process Task is not stopped and it is continuously running. Pls confirm how to resolve this issue .

Comment: @user2468951 Did you find anything for this issiue?